# C# Windows Form How to Datagridview to Database (Sql Server)?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I need Insert data in Datagridview to Database in Sql Server 2008. But don't work.

".Rows(i)" Message Error:

> 'Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Rows' cannot
>   be used like a method.'

**Code C# (Windows Form)**

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
SqlTransaction tr;

private void testExcel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string appConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connDB"].ConnectionString;
    Conn = new SqlConnection();
    if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        Conn.Close();

    }
    Conn.ConnectionString = appConn;
    Conn.Open();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tr = Conn.BeginTransaction();

    sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
    sb.Append("INSERT INTO tableAset (Id,AsId,AsRefid,Invid,TypeName)");
    sb.Append("VALUES (@Id,@AsId,@AsRefid,@Invid,@TypeName)");
    string sqlSave = sb.ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {     
      cmd.CommandText = sqlSave;
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.Connection = Conn;
      cmd.Transaction = tr;
      cmd.Parameters.Clear();

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@AsId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@AsRefid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Invid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@TypeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value;

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      tr.Commit();
      MessageBox.Show("It's Done!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your time. :)

Comment: try `.Rows[i]` and `Cells[n]` (is this converted VB code?)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **rows[i]** instead, the same goes for the Cells:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value
```

Take a look at the [Rows property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

just replace the round brackets with the square one

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use SqlBulkCopy.You can easily get the GridView data in DataTable format and you can pass the  DataTable to SqlBulkCopy WriteToServer
You can check this example.
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-SqlBulkCopy-to-insert-bulk-data-from-GridView-to-database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Please write the affected code in your answer and don't just refer a link to the solution.